# Best way to apply per neuron activation functions in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I want to use a custom activation function that has a random component that gets applied to every neuron individually.

If I use the standard method and call the activation function on a layer, it applies the same value to every neuron in that layer.

I am looking for the most efficient way to have the activation function affect every neuron individually and would appreciate any advise on the topic.

The only method I currently know about involves splitting the input tensor and applying the function each part and then concatenating the result, but I am hoping there is a more efficient way

Comment: Without more details I doubt there's going to be a satisfactory answer here. If you have implemented your activation using pytorch tensor operations then an easy solution is to replace the scalar random values in your implementation with tensors of random values that are the same shape as your input tensor.